# Different code styles in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I often need to make changes to projects that have different code styles. I for example use tabs and many other projects use spaces. Also I recently moved to egyptian braces style. Is it possible to define a code style on per project basis? Maybe there is some plugin that at least auto-detects indentation symbol (tabs-spaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org) plugin which not only allows to set per-project (or even per-file) style but also to share it with other developers using `.editorconfig` file in project root. It also works on other IDEs and is open source.

Comment: Also there is a ReBracer plugin that supports more functionality on per-solution basis (it just loads all VS formatting settings from xml when solution is opened)